# Aurelia layout is recreated on every route change

Tags: aurelia

**Background**

I have a typical web app with a left column menu; and a right column for content.

If I put a menu in the left column and use `<router-view></router-view>` in the right, as you would expect the content is swapped out as you navigate routes.

See a basic [gist.run here](https://gist.run/?id=87aaf4c98b7276d88a8db84fcccecbc9). This is obviously not my actual app so ignore the oversimplifications. You can see by clicking on one of the menu items it changes style, then click one of the home/page links and the menu item keeps its applied class.

**The problem**

If I add a layout for these two routes, the menu looses its state when changing routes. i.e. the applied "active" style is lost because the layout is reloaded, instead of just the slot being reloaded. [gist.run here](https://gist.run/?id=a3b5a506d7d257e4cc872ad2f6e0f5e0):
app.js:

```
config.map([
  { route: '', name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', layoutView: "layout.html", layoutViewModel: "layout" },
  { route: 'page', name: 'page', moduleId: 'page', layoutView: "layout.html", layoutViewModel: "layout" }
]);
```

layout.html:

```
<template>
  <!-- left menu content here -->
  <div class="layout">
  <!-- route view on right: -->
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

My home.html and route.html pages are identical to the previous gist without layouts:

```
<template>
  Home
</template>
```

Note that slots are not needed here (e.g. `<div slot="name">...`) because there is only one slot. I've tried including them and the result is the same.

I would expect that the layout/router behaviour should look the same - that the layout isn't reloaded on each route change - even though it's wired differently underneath.

This is a problem because I may have animations on the menu items (sliding, dropdowns, active classes etc.) and I don't want those starting from the default position each time a route is changed. I may also have controls in the left panel such as a search box or other form, and may not want that refreshing on each route change.

**Is there any way I can make the layout behave the same (keep "state") as the router-view?**

As a way around it I've considered:

- an initial state that I put together from the current route (could get messy or not cover all options)
- saving state in a service or singleton somehow, but I can't figure out if this is possible with a view
- router viewports. Not quite as flexible because I can't have multiple different app.html's with different viewports laid out in different ways. It also requires a module-per-viewport or other trickery, and can't have all the content from the same view as with slots...

Please tell me if there's something else I can do or if I'm doing it all wrong!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just yesterday asked about this over at the [Aurelia Gitter room](https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss), and the response I got was that layout lifecycle is tied to the routed module's lifecycle. In practice, this means that:

- If your `activationStrategy` is `refresh`, the layout will be destroyed and recreated *even when navigating to the same route with different parameters*.
- If your `activationStrategy` is `invokeLifecycle`, the layout will *not* be destroyed and recreated if you navigate to the *same* route, but it *will* be if you navigate to a different route.

So if you have some state that you want to keep in the parent structure, and still be able to have multiple positions where content is projected on a per-route basis, viewports are the way to go, with the caveats that you already noted.